# Silverlight 4 and SignalR

Tags: silverlight-4.0, signalr

I've read everything I could about SignalR and Silverlight, but I still cannot make it running. 
I've installed SignalR in Web project, and that went well. Then, I added dlls from here to SL4 project http://chris.59north.com/post/2011/12/15/SignalR-and-Silverlight.aspx. In the end, it says I missed SignalR.Client.Hubs namespace (SignalR). Whatever I do, I cannot find SignalR namespace in SL project.

Is there a way to run SignalR with SL4 or I should go to SL5? Does anyone have an example of SL application that is running SignalR. I really need this up and running, but I feel like that it is impossible...

Comment: are you using https://nuget.org/packages/SignalR.Client.Silverlight

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Silverlight 5 is the supported version for SignalR as per the client requirements on their page at http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms. So you will need to upgrade to SL 5.